# Equation signs disappeared

Tags: equations

I really hope someone can help me, because I'm soon submitting my master thesis and suddenly this happend:

All minus/plus/equal-signs have disappeared from my equations! They have been there all the time, but suddenly they are gone, and I have no idea how I made it happen.
I'm using the following math packages:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}
```

One of my equations looks like this:

```
\begin{equation}
CO + 2H_{\textrm{2}} \leftrightarrow CH_{\textrm{3}}OH 
\end{equation}
```

I'll be forever thankful for any help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The problem is not clear; can you expand a bit? Can you show a minimal example in which the problem appears?

Comment: I found out that it is the {lmodern} package which does it, but is there anyway I can use lmodern and still have the equations?

Comment: This is quite strange; I've used `lmodern` without experiencing any problem. Probably it's better if you show your document preamble.

Comment: looks like you where trying to rediscover something, why aren't you using a package like `chemmarcos`, `chemfig` or `mhchem`? Those are easier to use and provide better output ;) AFAK there is a possability to give them a number,too.

Comment: like @Rico says: `chemmacros` or `mhchem` are the way to go for chemical reactions. Both their macros for chemical formulae (`\ch{}` or `\ce{}`, resp.) can be used inside equations. `chemmacros` tries hard to ensure IUPAC's recommendations.

Answer (score 8):

Here an example that looks more like chemistry and also contains an equation with an equal sign:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \mathrm{CO} + 2\,\mathrm{H}_{\mathrm{2}} \rightleftharpoons \mathrm{CH}_{3}\textrm{OH}
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
    E=mc^2
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Remarks:

- `\textrm` inside the subscript makes the numbers too large.
- Atoms are set upright (`\mathrm`, `\text`, ...).
- Usually harpoons are used.

Typing and typesetting is easier with a package for chemistry, e.g. package `mhchem`. The example becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}% for \text
\usepackage{mhchem}% for \ce
\usepackage{chemarr}% for \xrightleftharpoons

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \ce{CO} + \ce{2H2} \xrightleftharpoons[\text{below}]{\text{above}} \ce{CH3OH}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The example can even be simplified using the full power of package `mhchem` (thanks cgnieder for the hint):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\ce{CO + 2H2 <=>[\text{above}][\text{below}] CH3OH}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Update:**

Package `mhchem` now requires that option `version` option is specified. Also the latest example can shortened by specifying text mode via `T` after the reaction arrows, thanks Martin for the [hint](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117876/equation-signs-disappeared/117882?noredirect=1#comment556152_117882).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\ce{CO + 2 H2 <=>T[below][above] CH3OH}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's even easier with `mhchem`: in the `{equation}` environment `\ce{CO + 2 H2 <=>[\text{below}][\text{above}] CH3OH}` would suffice.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that when I'm applying the lmodern package, the signs still disappear. I'm told to use the lmodern package in order to make sure the fonts have "embedded subsets" to make sure the printing is done correct. Any ideas to how I deal with this without loosing my equation signs?

Comment: @MarthaMarie: Is your `lmodern` installation uptodate?

Comment: @cgnieder: Thanks for the hint, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @MarthaMarie `lmodern` will not break things _unless_ you have a defective installation. Do you get any warnings in the log if you take Heiko's example and add loading of `lmodern` (with no other changes)?

Comment: If I only run @HeikoOberdiek's code it works fine, but somehow lmodern seems to ruin my equations. But it seems like my fonts are embedded anyway, so I'll just drop the lmodern package and hope the printing will go fine. Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: @MarthaMarie: Perhaps you can reinstall or update the Latin Modern fonts.

Comment: You can shorten the `mhchem` command to `\ce{CO + 2 H2 <=>T[below][above] CH3OH}`. Given no parameter after the reaction arrow, interprets it as math-code, `T`is for text and `C` is for mhchem statements.